# iscsiadm: No portal found

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, openstack

I am receiving an error saying 
"Trace nova Stderr:'iscsiadm:No portal found. \n'. 
Trace nova Command: sudo nova-rootwrap iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-0000003 -p :3260 --rescan

Plz let me know if further info is req. Thanks in advance.

Update:

There are two servers

1. Controller node (hostname: cc)

2. Compute node (hostname: nc)

**OS:** Ubuntu 12.04 (Headless)

**Openstack flavor:** Essex

We had our set up working fine till last week. But, when we wanted to install Ubuntu desktop to move out from Headless and get some beautiful screens, we had type the command (in cc host)

`#sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

And then and there all our problems started. I could notice that, it is removing Apache, Openstack – dashboard and nova volume also with out any prior notice or confirmation. It didn’t even update the things.

So all our VM instances went down.

And then, when I ran #sudo nova-manage service list, it use to show me XXX for nova-volume and nova-compute. We reinstalled nova-volume which changed the status from XXX to :-).

And then, we tried all the things we know like reinstalling apahce2, reinstalling openstack-dashboard, apt-get update, apt-get upgrade, removing suspecting records from mysql, removing lvm.

After this some how we could get our openstack dashboard up and running.
So now, our concern was about nova-compute service which was displaying XXX in service list.

**Attempt 1:** When we changed the nova.conf file with start_guests_on_host_boot=false and resume_guests_state_on_host_boot=false and rebooted the cc host, it displayed :-) for all services after reboot.
Now when I checked dashboard, it was displaying status as Shut off for all vms with spinner rotating.

**Attempt 2:** When we changed the nova.conf file with start_guests_on_host_boot=true and resume_guests_state_on_host_boot=true and rebooted the cc host, it displayed XXX for nova-compute service after reboot.
When we checked the /var/log/nova/nova-compute.log file, it displayed error like

`iscsiadm: No portal found. \n'. Trace nova Command: sudo nova-rootwrap iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2010-10.org.openstack: volume-0000003 -p: 3260 --rescan`

**Fix worked for above thing:**
1.Changed the two flags in nova conf to true.
2.Executed #apt-get remove --purge iscsitarget
3.Rebooted the cc host.
4.Executed #/etc/init.d/open-iscsi restart.
5.Executed #sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
6.Executed #sudo service ntp restart
7.Executed #sudo service tgt restart
8.Executed #sudo nova-manage db sync
9.Restarted nova-volume, nova-compute, nova-cert, nova-network, nova-scheduler, nova-consoleauth of cc host.

**Result of the fix:**
We were able to get (we did not get this before) volumes list when we ran the below command 

`#iscsiadm -m discovery -t sendtargets -p :3260

CC_HOST_IP:3260, 1 iqn.2010-10.org.openstack: volume-00000007

CC_HOST_IP:3260, 1 iqn.2010-10.org.openstack: volume-00000005

CC_HOST_IP:3260, 1 iqn.2010-10.org.openstack: volume-00000014

CC_HOST_IP:3260, 1 iqn.2010-10.org.openstack: volume-00000003

CC_HOST_IP:3260, 1 iqn.2010-10.org.openstack: volume-0000000f

CC_HOST_IP:3260, 1 iqn.2010-10.org.openstack: volume-00000013

CC_HOST_IP:3260, 1 iqn.2010-10.org.openstack: volume-00000004

CC_HOST_IP:3260, 1 iqn.2010-10.org.openstack: volume-00000008`

And still all the VMs were in status Shutoff and the spinner was spinning continuously for 1 whole day. We noticed that we were able to ping some of the VMs and also connect to them with MSTSC.

And now, we did not see the Portal not found error in the compute log. But we noticed error saying below.

`libvirtError: Unable to allow access for disk path /dev/disk/by-path/ip-:3260-iscsi-iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-00000017-lun-1: No such file or directory`

And for your information, as part of my R&D, I had deleted (lvremove volume-17) the lvm related to that.

**Current status:** On cc host, Getting the error as

`libvirtError: Unable to allow access for disk path /dev/disk/by-path/ip-:3260-iscsi-iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-00000017-lun-1: No such file or directory`

On nc host, getting error as

`libvirtError: Unable to allow access for disk path /dev/disk/by-path/ip-:3260-iscsi-iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-00000020-lun-1: No such file or directory`

**Inputs:**
1.  We don’t have cinder here. Only nova-volume, nova-compute, nova-cert, nova-network, nova-scheduler, nova-consoleauth.
2.  Current status of services is

`Binary		Host		Zone		Status		State 		Updated_At		
nova-network	cc		nova		enabled		:-)	2016-05-19 13:48:48

nova-compute	cc		nova		enabled		XXX	2016-05-19 11:37:23

nova-scheduler	cc		nova		enabled		:-)	   2016-05-19 13:48:51

nova-volume	cc		nova		enabled		:-)	2016-05-19 13:48:48

nova-consoleauth	cc	nova		enabled		:-)	2016-05-19 13:48:50

nova-cert	cc		nova		enabled		:-)	2016-05-19 13:48:49

nova-compute	nc		nova		enabled		XXX	2016-05-19 11:37:13

nova-volume	nc		nova		enabled		:-)	2016-05-19 13:48:44`

3. Yes, tgt is running.

   `root@cc:/dev/disk/by-path# sudo service tgt status
   tgt start/running, process 2583`
4. Config files are below.
   **nova.conf on cc host:**

   `--dhcpbridge_flagfile=/etc/nova/nova.conf
   --my_ip=
   --dhcpbridge=/usr/bin/nova-dhcpbridge
   --logdir=/var/log/nova
   --debug = true
   --state_path=/var/lib/nova
   --lock_path=/run/lock/nova
   --allow_admin_api=true
   --use_deprecated_auth=false
   --auth_strategy=keystone
   --scheduler_driver=nova.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler
   --max_cores=106
   --s3_host=
   --ec2_host=
   --rabbit_host=
   --cc_host=
   --nova_url=http://:8774/v1.1/
   --routing_source_ip=
   --glance_api_servers=:9292
   --image_service=nova.image.glance.GlanceImageService
   --iscsi_ip_prefix=192.168.4
   --sql_connection=mysql://nova:nova@/nova
   --ec2_url=http://:8773/services/Cloud
   --keystone_ec2_url=http://:5000/v2.0/ec2tokens
   --api_paste_config=/etc/nova/api-paste.ini
   --libvirt_type=kvm
   --libvirt_use_virtio_for_bridges=true
   --start_guests_on_host_boot=true
   --resume_guests_state_on_host_boot=true
   --novnc_enabled=true
   --novncproxy_base_url=http://:6080/vnc_auto.html
   --vncserver_proxyclient_address=
   --vncserver_listen=
   --vncserver_listen=0.0.0.0
   --network_manager=nova.network.manager.FlatDHCPManager
   --public_interface=eth0
   --flat_interface=eth1
   --flat_network_bridge=br100
   --fixed_range=192.xxx.y.1/27
   --floating_range=/27
   --network_size=32
   --flat_network_dhcp_start=192.xxx.y.33
   --flat_injected=False
   --force_dhcp_release=True
   --iscsi_helper=tgtadm
   --connection_type=libvirt
   --root_helper=sudo nova-rootwrap
   --verbose`

**nova.conf on nc host:**
	
`--dhcpbridge_flagfile=/etc/nova/nova.conf
--my_ip=
--dhcpbridge=/usr/bin/nova-dhcpbridge
--logdir=/var/log/nova
--state_path=/var/lib/nova
--lock_path=/run/lock/nova
--allow_admin_api=true
--use_deprecated_auth=false
--auth_strategy=keystone
--scheduler_driver=nova.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler
--max_cores=106
--s3_host=
--ec2_host=
--rabbit_host=
--cc_host=
--nova_url=http://:8774/v1.1/
--routing_source_ip=
--glance_api_servers=:9292
--image_service=nova.image.glance.GlanceImageService
--iscsi_ip_prefix=192.xxx.y
--sql_connection=mysql://nova:cyient#3@/nova
--ec2_url=http://:8773/services/Cloud
--keystone_ec2_url=http://:5000/v2.0/ec2tokens
--api_paste_config=/etc/nova/api-paste.ini
--libvirt_type=kvm
--libvirt_use_virtio_for_bridges=true
--start_guests_on_host_boot=true
--resume_guests_state_on_host_boot=true
--novnc_enabled=true
--novncproxy_base_url=http://:6080/vnc_auto.html
--vncserver_proxyclient_address=
--vncserver_listen=0.0.0.0
--network_manager=nova.network.manager.FlatDHCPManager
--public_interface=eth0
--flat_interface=eth1
--flat_network_bridge=br100
--fixed_range=192.xxx.y.1/27
--floating_range=/27
--network_size=32
--flat_network_dhcp_start=192.xxx.y.33
--flat_injected=false
--force_dhcp_release=true
--iscsi_helper=tgtadm
--connection_type=libvirt
--root_helper=sudo nova-rootwrap
--verbose`

**Update**:
Got the above two errors fixed by below explained steps

1. In cc host, I made the flags `start_guests_on_host_boot=false` and `resume_guests_state_on_host_boot`.
2. Rebooted the cc and nc hosts.
3. After reboot, all the nova services displayed `:-)`.
4. Deleted the records from mysql db whose deleted status is 1.
5. Changed the status of the each and every vm to `mysql: update instances set vm_state='active', task_state = NULL, power_state = 1  where uuid = INSTANCE_UUID`
6. Rebooted each and every vm using the command `#nova reboot --hard INSTANCE_UUID`
7. This solved my problem and got all my VM up and running.
8. Restored the above two boolean flags to true and rebooted cc host.
9. After reboot, all nova services were `:-)` and all VMs are up and running.

Comment: When , where, what, why and how would be useful

Comment: I am trying to setup openstack essex on ubuntu 12.04. So when I restart my nova services, i get XXX for nova compute. And in logs, I found error saying "libvirtError:Unable to allow access for disk path /dev/disk/by-path/ip-<controller>:3260-iscsi-iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-00000017-lun-1:No such file or directory"

Comment: that's version 4 of openstack, version 13 is out now

Comment: Yeah, but my lead wants to set it up with essex only for some reason.

Comment: well, you haven't supplied enough information to troubleshoot

Comment: What info do you need.

Comment: lots! - your config, your cinder driver, some logs, current state of services - here is a quick thing to check is the tgt service running? - unless you can document your configuration and ask a specific question then you might as well just start googling.

Comment: I have updated the things. Please let me know if anything is required.

Comment: ok so both of your nova compute services are disabled for some reason, we need to look at the nova-compute logs, can you try and start the service **service nova-compute start** and then look at the nova-compute log, should be something like **tail -f /var/log/nova/nova-compute.log**. This **may** point to errors with libvirt and iscsi volumes, so, see if you can login to the volumes that you discovered, for example **iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2010-10.org.openstack: volume-00000007 -p CC_HOST_IP:3260 --login** - VM's will not boot until the compute service is enabled.

Comment: Now instances are up some how. But, a volume is shown as attached in mysql db where as it is not showing in the VM. I checked the logs, I found a  error like **83, in detach_volume
2016-05-24 15:01:05 TRACE nova.rpc.amqp     raise exception.DiskNotFound(location=mount_device)
2016-05-24 15:01:05 TRACE nova.rpc.amqp DiskNotFound: No disk at vdc**

Comment: Look at the output of **nova volume-list** and the output of **lvdisplay** is there a volume missing or any errors?

Comment: Executed nova volume-list but, the volume I am looking for is present and in lvdisplay also, the lv information is displayed

Comment: it looks to be attached, probably you need to log into the VM and mount the volume, check in the disk management console or /etc/fstab if Linux

Comment: It is a windows 7 VM. And I checked in the Disk management tool, the volume is not displayed only root (Local disk C) and ephemeral disk(Local disk D) are displayed.

Comment: Earlier, I had deleted the iqn from the path #/etc/iscsi/nodes. by using the following command #rm -rf iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-00000003

Comment: what made you do that? - if you need to delete those you have to use iscsiadm, anyway see if you can rediscover your iscsi targets **iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p CC_HOST_IP:3260**

Comment: Yeah it is discoverable. It printed **CC_HOST_IP:3260,1 iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-00000003**. This is the volume attached to an instance and the volume is not getting displayed in Disk management.

Comment: And  I observed that lun is not present in the path **/dev/disk/by-path**. For all other volumes a lun is present like **ip-CC_HOST_IP:3260-iscsi-iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-00000090-lun-1**

Comment: if it's discovered, try logging in again - any errors?

Comment: It is successfull. **Login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-00000003, portal: CC_HOST_IP,3260]: successful**

Comment: after executing login, a lun got created in the folder. But still, facing issue for detaching or attaching the volume to the instance.

Comment: When I run the command **iscsiadm -m node**, it displayed all my volumes except the **volume-00000003**

Comment: we've taken this as far as it can go in the comments section, I would advise you to troubleshoot, as far as OpenStack is concerned, find out what the volume state is (attached, available etc) and try some of the reset-state commands